# get only specific element of a JSON database stored in server by url request

Tags: javascript, json, database, rest, api

my website relies on a database which is a big JSON file like this:

```
var myjsonData = 
[ {
"ID": 0,
"name": "Henry",
"surname": "McLarry",
"...": "...",
}]
```

I do generate this data every month at high cost to me, therefore I would like to avoid calling it straight in my html `<head>`, because this will allow any user to download the full database in no time.

I would like to build a "something" that can only call specific items from the json file (just the only one I want to show) without "exposing" the full .json onto client side.

today I use the call

`var myvar= myjsonData.ID.Name`

to get "Henry" into myvar, I would like to build something like

```
var myvar = mycallfunction(ID,Name)
```

I did try with PHP as intermediary but the ajax calls from javacript doesn't allow me to fetch the data.

Can I use JQuery with the JSON Url to get only the item I need?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is parse your json for an object. So you can get any value you want from json.
Example:

```
var myjsonData = '{"ID": 0,"name": "Henry","surname": "McLarry"}';
obj = JSON.parse(myjsonData);
console.log(myjsonData.ID);           //print the id
console.log(myjsonData.name);         //print the name
console.log(myjsonData.surname);      //print the surname
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have a NoSQL Database which has only one kind of Document that is the full JSON element you use in your website. In that scenario you have three options:

1. Depending on the NoSQL Database you're using you can limit the fields which will be returned(I.e: For MongoDB you can look here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)
2. Change the way you store you data into more modular documents and make the logic to connect them in you application. So instead of one big document you'll have modular ones as Users, Products, Transactions and etc and you can use your application to query them individually.
3. Build a Server Side logic as an API to deal with your data and provide only what you need, so the API(Which can be node.js, php, or any you may like) will get the full JSON it`s endpoints will only the data you want. For example: myapi.com/getUser, myapi.com/getProducts and so on.

If you're able to provide more info on the technologies you're using that would help us. Hope that helped :).

Comment: thanks Gustavo. Indeed I was trying to build an API with PHP but jquery asyncronicity requires me to use Promises and that is effectively excluding IE users from my website. I agree with you the most robust solution is SQL database.